# How do I make the MinGW cross compiler use the same libraries as gcc?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, mingw

My program uses the GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library to deal with numbers of an arbitrary size. I successfully compile it using GCC with:

```
gcc main.c -o diff -g -lgmp
```

However, when I try to use the MinGW crosscompiler compiler, I get the following error:

```
i686-w64-mingw32-gcc main.c -o diff.exe -g -lgmp
main.c:3:46: fatal error: gmp.h: No such file or directory
 #include <gmp.h>//For files of arbitrary size
```

I then tried to tell it exactly where the header file was:

```
 i686-w64-mingw32-gcc main.c -o diff.exe -I/usr/include -g -lgmp
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: cannot find -lgmp
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Ok, so I figure now it successfully found the header, but cant find the library. So I tried again:

```
i686-w64-mingw32-gcc main.c -o diff.exe -I/usr/include -g -L/usr/lib -lgmp
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: cannot find -lgmp
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I guess I need to specify the exact files to use, so I tried this:

```
i686-w64-mingw32-gcc main.c -o diff.exe -I/usr/include -g /usr/lib/libgmp.so
/usr/lib/libgmp.so: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So, I honestly don't know what to do and I'd really really appreciate your help.

Comment: You need to cross-compile the library, too!

Comment: You don't. It won't work.

Answer (score 3):

First, a disclaimer: the cross-compiler you are using is neither distributed by, nor supported by MinGW.org, whom I represent; if you are looking for a pre-compiled solution, you should seek it from the distributor of the specific cross-compiler itself.

That said, I can offer the following insight, (which will apply, in general, to any cross-compiler): the headers you find in `/usr/include`, or in `/usr/local/include`, and the `libgmp.so` which you find in `/usr/lib`, or in `/usr/local/lib`, are intended for use with your native platform compiler. They are not suitable for, and *cannot* be used with your MinGW cross-compiler; attempting to do so will surely never work. Thus, you have two options:

1. Ask your cross-compiler distributor to provide a pre-compiled copy of gmp.dll, (or at the very least, a compatible import library, although you may need the gmp.dll to distribute with your own application anyway), and any associated header files, and/or equivalent statically linkable library, for use with your cross-compiler.
2. Use your cross-compiler to build gmp.dll yourself, then install it, its associated headers, and perhaps also its associated import library and/or equivalent statically linkable library, into the same prefix-path as the cross-compiler itself.